# How can I implement KSQLDB init script?

Tags: ksqldb

I'm deploying KSQLDB in a docker container and I need to create some tables (if they don't exist) when the database starts. Is there a way to do that? Any examples?

Answer (score 0):

As of version 0.11 you would need to have something that could query the servers rest endpoint to determine what tables existed, and then submit SQL to create any missing tables.  This is obviously a little clunky.

I believe the soon to be released 0.12 release comes with [`CREATE OR REPLACE`](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/2440) support for creating streams and tables. With this feature all you'd need is a script with a few curl commands within your docker image that waited for the server to become available and then fired in a SQL script with your table definitions using `CREATE OR REPLACE`.

The 0.12 release also comes with `IF NOT EXIST` syntax support for streams, tables, connectors and types. So you can do:

```sql
CREATE STREAM IF NOT EXISTS FOO (ID INT) WITH (..);
```

Details of what to pass to the server can be found in the [Rest API docs](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/ksqldb-rest-api/ksql-endpoint/).

Or you should be able to script sending in the commands using the CLI.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure if CREATE OR REPLACE will work for me, I only need to create tables and streams if they don't exist, not replacing them every time. So I guess I will have to use the rest api and add some logic. Clunky, true, but I see no other option.

Comment: 0.12 also has `IF NOT EXIST` support, which may suit you better.